# Create a program that allows the user to convert a range of values from feet to centimeter or centimeter to feet

Tags: python, range

I'm having a hard time including the conversion rates and the range. Can you help me with this? I'm a beginner programming in Python. Thank you so much. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PW99.jpg)]

Sample of expected output:

```
This program will convert a range of LENGTH 
Enter (F) to convert Feet to Centimeter 
Enter (C to convert Centimeter to Feet 

Enter Selection: F 
Enter starting length to convert: 10 
Enter ending length to convert: 20 

 Length Length 
Feet Centimeter 
  10.0 304.8
  11.0 335.3 
  12.0 365.8 
  13.0 396.2 
  14.0 426.7 
  15.0 457.2 
  16.0 487.7 
  17.0 518.2 
  18.0 548.6 
  19.0 579.1 
  20.0 609.6
```

Here's my initial input, but I really can't manage to do it. [image]

```
print("This program will convert a range of LENGTH ")
print("Enter (F) to convert Feet to Centimeter")
print("Enter (C) to convert Centimeter to Feet")
print()
feet = 'F'
centimeter = 'C'
which = input("Enter Selection: ",  )
meas_start = int(input("Enter starting length to convert: "))
meas_end = int(input("Enter ending length to convert: "))
print()
print(" Length Length")
print("Feet Centimeter")
if meas_start == feet:
```

Comment: Please share you code as text instead of as an image :)

Comment: Is there some input and output given to you?

Comment: Will put the sample output above. Thank you! @codester_09

Comment: @KuroshSigariAvendano edit this in your code so I can see it in the formatted way.

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to program this? @codester_09 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74339454/program-handling-library-book-count-of-borrowed-and-returned-books-borrow-retu?noredirect=1#comment131239975_74339454

Comment: @KuroshSigariAvendano I will check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
print("This program will convert a range of LENGTH ")
print("Enter (F) to convert Feet to Centimeter")
print("Enter (C) to convert Centimeter to Feet")
print()
feet = 'F'
centimeter = 'C'
which = input("Enter Selection: ",  )
meas_start = int(input("Enter starting length to convert: "))
meas_end = int(input("Enter ending length to convert: "))
print()
print(" Length Length")

if which == feet:
    print("Feet Centimeter")
    for length in range(meas_start,meas_end + 1):
        print(f"{float(length)}  {round(length*30.48,1)}")

elif which == centimeter:
    print("Feet Centimeter")
    for length in range(meas_start, meas_end + 1):
        print(f"{float(length)}  {round(length/30.48,1)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#This function converts ft to cm 
def cm(x):
    return x / 30.48

#This function converts cm to ft
def ft(x):
    return x / 0.0328084

def decimal_range(start, stop, increment):
    while start < stop+1:
        yield start
        start += increment

print("This program will convert a range of LENGTH ")
print("Enter (F) to convert Feet to Centimeter")
print("Enter (C) to convert Centimete to Feet")
print()

#take input from the user
which = input("Enter Selection: ",  )

#checking of selection
if which == 'C':
    meas_start = float(input("Enter starting length to convert: "))
    meas_end = float(input("Enter ending length to convert: "))
    print()
    print(" Length Length")
    print("Centimeter Feet")
    for i in decimal_range(meas_start, meas_end,1):
        print (" ", i,"  ", round(cm(i),1))
elif which == 'F':
    meas_start = float(input("Enter starting length to convert: "))
    meas_end = float(input("Enter ending length to convert: "))
    print()
    print(" Length Length")
    print("Feet Centimeter")
    for i in decimal_range(meas_start, meas_end,1):
            print (" ", i," ", round(ft(i),1))
else:
    print ("Invalid Input")
```